# Android Share binary data using Intent.ACTION_SEND

Tags: java, android, android-intent, binary, share

I'm developing an application that share binary data (videos, musics) via bluetooth and so on. I'm using ACTION_SEND intent for that, but my device Toast a message like "File help.apk was not sent". My code is here:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
shareIntent.setType("*/*");
File  fayl = new File("file:///" + "mnt/apps/help.apk");
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(fayl);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
startActivity(shareIntent);
```

Comment: That file may not be readable by the other app.